Optimal combination of feature values to maximize a metric
I'm facing a complex issue with a project I'm working on and would appreciate some advice. Here's the context:
We have a search engine where users input queries and get results filtered through Elasticsearch. There are around 50 numeric continuous filters available.
The filters are for example : rating of the product, number of comments under the product... the goal is to choose a subset of filters to focus on and then find the optimal values for each filter.
The challenge is to determine the optimal values for these filters to yield the most relevant results for a given query. The value of the filters are going to be constant and independent from the query.
My current approach involves annotating a set of products as relevant or not relevant to the query, then adjusting the filter values and observing changes in the F1-score for the "relevant" class until I find the optimal combination.
However, I am looking for a more robust methodology. Can anyone provide guidance or recommend a better approach?
Thank you!
